# data transition is not working for external link

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

```
<div data-role="header" id="header"> <h1>Qsr Food</h1> <a href="info.html" rel="external" data-icon="info" data-iconpos="notext" data-rel="dialog" data-transition = "flip" class="ui-btn-right">info</a> </div><!------- header div-----> <div data-role="content" id="content"> </div><!----- main div------->
```

and here is info.html code

```
<div data-role="dialog" id="info" data-theme="e" data-transition="flip"> <div data-role="header"> <h1>About View Source</h1> </div>

<div data-role="content">
<p> View Source offers short projects on intermediate to advanced web design topics, coveing technologies such as HTML, PHP< JQuery, and CSS, as well as content management solutions like WordPress and integration with Twitter, YouTube, and more.</p>
</div>
```

whats wrong with me

Comment: I do not see a question here.... :-\

Comment: transition to info.html is not working

Answer (score 1):

Adding `rel=external` will effectively stop the transition. For `data-transition` to work, load the scripts which pertain to `info.html` in the first page itself and remove `rel = external` from your link.

For dialog boxes, remove `rel=external` and you'll do just fine. No extra JavaScript needed. Let the magic work itself :-)

**Extra references**

- [Dialog widgets API docs](http://api.jquerymobile.com/dialog/)

**Important**

These methods will not work in chrome desktop version but in mobile version it does. There's no other way but to use `rel= external` for working with chrome.

Answer (score 1):

To open an external HTML as a dialog, use the following code

HTML - link to your dialog.html with id `dialog`.

```
<a href="#" id="dialog" data-icon="info" data-iconpos="notext">info</a>
```

jQuery Mobile

```
$(document).on('click', '#dialog', function() {
 $.mobile.changePage('dialog.html', { role: 'dialog', transition: 'flip' });
});
```